# How can I set a timeout for a locked table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, function, locking

I want to set a timeout for this query. How can I do ?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."testlock"()
    RETURNS TABLE
    (
         id integer,
         name character varying
    ) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
     BEGIN  
        LOCK TABLE public."lock" IN ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE; 
                UPDATE public."lock" as l set name = 'deneme' WHERE l."id" = 4;

        return query        
            select l."id",l."name" from public."lock" as l, pg_sleep(10) where l."id" = 4;

    END; 
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Why do you want to lock the whole table when you only update a single row? (You can also combine the UPDATE and SELECT into a single statement

Comment: because I am calling to table from another place,so I have to set timeout some table.

Comment: The UPDATE will already lock the row you are interested in. I don't see any reason to block all access to the table just to update a single row

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you should merge `UPDATE` and `SELECT` into a single statement. `UPDATE` ***will*** lock the updated rows in `ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE`. Thus the `LOCK` statement ist unnecessary. The code in the function then looks like this:

```
RETURN QUERY UPDATE public."lock" as l set name = 'deneme' WHERE l."id" = 4
    RETURNING l."id", l."name";
```

You can't set and use a statement timeout inside of a function. See [How we can make “statement_timeout” work inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873517/how-we-can-make-statement-timeout-work-inside-a-function)

Comment: I did that but It can not set timeout like that. If I call function like ; 
SET statement_timeout TO 5000; 
COMMIT;
select * from public."testlock"();
its working. But I want to use in function.